# Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object

Tags: r, ggplot2, fortify

I'm trying to work with bike share system data, which can be found here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/hubway-data/202002-bluebikes-tripdata.zip

I can read the csv in fine, but when I try to plot it using ggplot I keep getting this message:

*Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class LayerInstance/Layer/ggproto/gg*

What's going on here? I am pretty new to coding and I don't know what an S3 object is, or how to work around this error.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to pass on ggplot layer as the data argument to either a layer or `ggplot()` itself. I don't see any code without downloading a file I don't necessarily trust, so I'm not sure where the error happens.

Comment: Hi Bailey - can you post your data via `dput(your.data.frame)` or at least a portion of your dataset?  You can use `dput(head(your.data.frame, x))`, where "x" is the number of rows of data to output if your dataset is very large.  As u/teunbrand mentioned, it's hard to help you without seeing the code you are using to try to plot and at least a snippet of the dataset.  Make sure to add them in the body of your question via "edit".  [For more information, see this link on suggestions for how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Thanks for posting!